# Как сконвертировать цену в ЧПФ?

Tags: php, числа, форматирование, конвертация, конвертер

Как конвертировать цифру в человеко-понятную форму?
Доспустим для построения счета на оплату нам нужно:
2000.00 -> Две тысячи рублей 00 копеек

Как правильно конвертировать, чтобы остались копейки? Пробую применить [INTL](http://php.mirrors.networking4all.com/manual/ru/book.intl.php) вот так:

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("ru", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format(1432.88);
```

Выдает "одна тысяча четыреста тридцать два запятая восемь восемь". Как это исправить?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php подойдет?

Comment: нет, нужно получить именно: "Две тысячи рублей 00 копеек"

Comment: А вы то что после запятой заранее вырезайте, конвертируйте целую часть и дописывайте дробную

Comment: Ну это костыль..NumberFormatter специально для этого предназначен, но что то не получается сделать так..

Comment: @entermix - `NumberFormatter`, а не `MoneyFormatter`

Comment: @igor, а где вы увидели MoneyFormatter?

Answer (score 2):

```
    
/**
 * Возвращает сумму прописью
 * @author runcore
 * @uses morph(...)
 */
function num2str($num) {
    $nul='ноль';
    $ten=array(
        array('','один','два','три','четыре','пять','шесть','семь', 'восемь','девять'),
        array('','одна','две','три','четыре','пять','шесть','семь', 'восемь','девять'),
    );
    $a20=array('десять','одиннадцать','двенадцать','тринадцать','четырнадцать' ,'пятнадцать','шестнадцать','семнадцать','восемнадцать','девятнадцать');
    $tens=array(2=>'двадцать','тридцать','сорок','пятьдесят','шестьдесят','семьдесят' ,'восемьдесят','девяносто');
    $hundred=array('','сто','двести','триста','четыреста','пятьсот','шестьсот', 'семьсот','восемьсот','девятьсот');
    $unit=array( // Units
        array('копейка' ,'копейки' ,'копеек',    1),
        array('рубль'   ,'рубля'   ,'рублей'    ,0),
        array('тысяча'  ,'тысячи'  ,'тысяч'     ,1),
        array('миллион' ,'миллиона','миллионов' ,0),
        array('миллиард','милиарда','миллиардов',0),
    );
    //
    list($rub,$kop) = explode('.',sprintf("%015.2f", floatval($num)));
    $out = array();
    if (intval($rub)>0) {
        foreach(str_split($rub,3) as $uk=>$v) { // by 3 symbols
            if (!intval($v)) continue;
            $uk = sizeof($unit)-$uk-1; // unit key
            $gender = $unit[$uk][3];
            list($i1,$i2,$i3) = array_map('intval',str_split($v,1));
            // mega-logic
            $out[] = $hundred[$i1]; # 1xx-9xx
            if ($i2>1) $out[]= $tens[$i2].' '.$ten[$gender][$i3]; # 20-99
            else $out[]= $i2>0 ? $a20[$i3] : $ten[$gender][$i3]; # 10-19 | 1-9
            // units without rub & kop
            if ($uk>1) $out[]= morph($v,$unit[$uk][0],$unit[$uk][1],$unit[$uk][2]);
        } //foreach
    }
    else $out[] = $nul;
    $out[] = morph(intval($rub), $unit[1][0],$unit[1][1],$unit[1][2]); // rub
    $out[] = $kop.' '.morph($kop,$unit[0][0],$unit[0][1],$unit[0][2]); // kop
    return trim(preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', join(' ',$out)));
}

/**
 * Склоняем словоформу
 * @ author runcore
 */
function morph($n, $f1, $f2, $f5) {
    $n = abs(intval($n)) % 100;
    if ($n>10 && $n1 && $n

    Взято с https://habrahabr.ru/post/53210/
```